# Prevent jQuery Tab from Performing Transitioning Effect on Active Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery tabs, and I currently have a slide effect whenever you click on a tab. My question is: How do you prevent a slide effect from happening on the current active tab if you click it again.

Here is my jQUery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#tabs').tabs();
 $("#tabs a").click(function() {
    $('#tabs p').effect( "slide", "medium" );
 });
});
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YRp62/2/

If you click "Second" and then click "Second" again. It slides into itself. How do you break the effect if you click on the active tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use tabs `activate` event instread of `click` event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tabs').tabs({
 activate: function(event, ui){
     $('#tabs p').effect( "slide", "medium" );
    }
  });   
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YRp62/3/)